# Xamarin.ios Settings.bundle Root.plist missing

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am using xamarin studio comunity. I found an error in my application settings.bundle root.plist missing. How to fix that error?

Answer (score 1):

Is your folder is named `"Settings.bundle"` and the file is `"Root.plist"`. And root.plist is it marked as `"Content"` and `"Always Copy"`. Sometimes is just casesensitive problems. If all names are correct, try to delete the Root.plist and adding it again by doing a right click on Settings.bundle and Add>New File>Property List. Don't forget to re-set properties `"Content"` and `"Always Copy"`