# Settings bundle is not displayed in iOS Settings app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have created a brand new Xamarin app, added Settings.bundle folder and Root.plist inside:
[image]
But in the emulator there is nothing in Settings app under my test application:
[image]

What do I miss or do wrong?

Comment: all looks good, try to remove old app, clean project and build again

Comment: Did it many of times, even created a new blank app with the settings only - no luck

Comment: Check if the property for a plist file is set at "Always copy" or "Bundle Resource"

Comment: Build action: Bundle Resource; Copy to output directory: Always copy

Comment: maybe this one could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272044/xamarin-ios-settings-bundle-root-plist-missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get it working with a help of Xcode: create a project there and add Settings bundle item
[image]
It will create a file with a correct XML structure (*Visual Studio doesn't do it even if you add new Property List file*). Then just copy and paste the Settings.bundle file physically to your Xamarin iOS project and edit in Visual Studio as needed.